# Why is every SELECT via a geometry function null?

Tags: ogr, spatialite

I'm using Spatialite (2.3.1, binary from the website) on Windows XP via Java ("Xerial Driver"). SQLite loads fine, also Spatialite seems to be loading successfully. I can even do SELECT-statements. But I can't do SELECT's on geometries. E.g.

```
SELECT link_id, SRID(GEOMETRY), AsText(GEOMETRY) FROM streets1
```

returns only null columns except for link_id. How can that be? By the way, I imported this data originally from MapInfo files using ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrc 8.6688 50.1018 8.6794 50.1082 -f "SQLite" streets1.SQLite ~/Desktop/G2AM10101EG2000MAADT/Streets1.TAB
```

Also I tried:

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrc 8.6688 50.1018 8.6794 50.1082 -f "SQLite" streets1.SQLite Streets1.TAB nlt GEOMETRY
```

This also gives the same result...

Thanks, Philip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution:

The tables are in FDO-Ogr format, you can see that when opening the db with spatialite-gui. Then you need to do:

```
SELECT AutoFDOStart();
```

and

```
SELECT link_id, SRID(GEOMETRY), AsText(GEOMETRY) FROM fdo_streets1
```

instead of

```
SELECT link_id, SRID(GEOMETRY), AsText(GEOMETRY) FROM streets1
```

C.f. here: http://groups.google.com/group/spatialite-users/browse_thread/thread/6750ad7013689a3d

Answer (score 2):

returning NULL and not an error means that the columns are empty or GEOMETRY is in WKB or WKT format and not in SPATIALITE.

WKB is the default for ogr2ogr, see [here](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_sqlite.html), so it's probably the problem.

Solutions:
1)use: `SELECT AsText(GeomFromWKB(GEOMETRY))`

or

2)put layer creation option `FORMAT=SPATIALITE` in ogr2ogr