# Calculating length of polyline using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, length

I have a polyline shapefile that has only one polyline.

How do I calculate the length of that polyline using ArcPy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [shape tokens](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/reading-geometries.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_A32D35B769484AA0A235BB6BACA3C517): this is the fastest and arguably the least expensive way to get the length of a feature.

Make sure though that you're accessing the distance values using a proper coordinate system so the values make sense. For instance, if your polyline is located geographically in California, US, and stored using geographic coordinate system `WGS84` (EPSG 4326), then you could, for instance, use a projected coordinate system `NAD_1983_California_Teale_Albers` (EPSG 3310) to re-project the feature on-the-fly getting the proper length value. This is done by supplying a [spatial reference object](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/spatialreference.htm) to the cursor.

1. You can run this code in ArcMap Python window (provided that the name of the shapefile is `Lines`.).

`[f[0] for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r"C:\GIS\Lines.shp", 'SHAPE@LENGTH')][0]`

Or in another coordinate system:

`[f[0] for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r"C:\GIS\Lines.shp", 'SHAPE@LENGTH', spatial_reference=arcpy.SpatialReference(3310))][0]`

2. Or as a standalone script

Code:

```
import arcpy
print([f[0] for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r"C:\GIS\Lines.shp", 'SHAPE@LENGTH')][0])
```

Comment: How do I change the units of the length?

Comment: @pnkjmndhl, updated the answer!

Comment: Thanks for the update, my current coordinate system is WGS1984. However, the polyline can lie anywhere in the US. So, I cant project in a specific state. Can I still project to a fixed projection and still get a reliable distance?

Comment: I am not the best one to talk to regarding the choice of projections for the US, but I think you should be fine with the `North_America_Lambert_Conformal_Conic
WKID: 102009` in ArcGIS. More links: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78141/coordinate-system-for-calculating-distance-at-the-nation-scale and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91007/geodesic-measurements-for-short-distances-throughout-us